# Add to cart button with icon in front

Tags: html, button, fonts, icons

I'm having some html problems, was looking everywhere but couldn't find the right answer.

I need an add to cart button with font awesome icon in front.
The orig html is:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>[ADD_TO_CART]</a>
```

I need to convert it into this code:

```
<input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="mod_bakery_bt_add_f" value="[ADD_TO_CART]" />
```

Comment: Got it ;) `<button type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" value="[ADD_TO_CART]">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> [ADD_TO_CART]
</button>` thx